# How do large sites store data over multiple servers?

Tags: database, web-applications, scalability

Say I was to build a web application using PHP and using a database to store the data of each user. I develop the site, get hold of a dedicated server, and start advertising my product. Over time my site gets more and more people registering and eventually all their data starts filling up the terabyte hard drive in my server until it is apparent I need more disk space.

My question is how is this accomplished without mindlessly adding disks to the same server until I can't possibly cram any more in, without segregating large amounts of user data? If my original server has the site pages on it along with the user data, when I add a second server at what point does the system say "that data is on that server and not the other one", where do I put the pages, and which server does the user see when they type in the url of my site if they're both wielding identical copies of the same site with a different bank of data? How do large companies (salesforce, google) accomplish this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Build your app on top of [Amazon Web services](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/aws-solutions/) or [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) and let them worry about this since it's fairly complex.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question but it's good enough for me. After checking out AWS I can see scalability won't be a huge issue with them, just need to make sure my coding is up to the task.

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin asking - do you really need to persist? yes, some times your application may be just a pipeline connecting source to the sink. Assuming, you do need to persist data, start questioning the needs and you will come to know a bit more about how the stored data is deemed to queried for later use. Think write heavy, read heavy, hybrid. Here, you will identify that not all data is queried together and that they vary in cadence. It would make sense to store data with similar cadence in the same unit. Assuming, your application is generating enough data which needs to be distributed on different machines. You would like to make optimal use of multiple machines so that all participating machines handle comparable compute/storage request. Here, you would need identify your sharding policy. Now that data is distributed you may face partial failures say machine storing users with names between N-S is down. In case, you need high availability i.e. you need access to all data at most times you need to replicate data on multiple machines which will reduce your total storage capacity and depending upon the size of the resulting cluster you may face consistency related issue. Depending upon your tolerance to inconsistent data you may like to think about your solution that may range between eventually consistent to a quorum based solution where you a piece of data available when a certain number of writes are committed.

Also think about the certain other aspects like time to live, last N items only, archival/invalidation of 'old/unused' data.

Hope that helps you to think about the resulting solution.